# laravel 4 validation - validation dont work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've started working with Laravel 4 Beta 2 and am running into a problem with the validation.

I have this route :

```
Route::post('inscription', function()
{   
    $rules = array(
        array('nom' => 'required'),
        array('passe' => 'required')
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        echo var_dump(Input::all());
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        print_R($messages->all());
    }
});
```

And I get that when I enter values in my form :

```
array (size=2)
  'nom' => string 'Dupont' (length=6)
  'passe' => string 'monpasse' (length=8)

Array ( [0] => The 0 field is required. [1] => The 1 field is required. )
```

That tell me fields are required but there are values !

Answer (score 3):

Ok I was wrong, here's the correct code :

```
Route::post('inscription', function()
{   
    $rules = array(
        'nom' => 'required',
        'passe' => 'required'
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    echo var_dump(Input::all());
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    print_R($messages->all());
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a beta version you should create an issue on github to get a good answer for your problem. The community will gladly help you.

https://github.com/laravel/framework

Comment: It's not an issue, I made a syntax error in my rules array. Must be a simple array.